# How to use arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am very new to java and I would like to know, what should I do when I want to use an array? I know that there is the normal arrays and the arraylists but which is better? Which is fastest when dealing with integers? How would I add a value? How would I read a value from an index? If you think that there is some more information that I should know about arrays please tell me.

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Care to summarize the contents of that document? If it goes offline or the site is re-organized, this post won't be much help to others in the future. (We're a _question_ and _answer_ site, not a _forum_, so we expect our answers to be able to reasonably stand on their own.) Thanks!

Comment: For a question of this level and a document so fundamental and commonly available, I don't think it's worth summarizing it here.

Answer (score 4):

Differences between arrays and `ArrayList`:

1. Arrays are faster than `ArrayLists`, but cannot grow, while `ArrayLists` can.
2. Arrays can hold primitive types, like `int`, `double`, `char` and they all get initialized automatically to zeros. You don't really "add" them to the array, you just change values already there after declaring it. On the other hand, the generic `ArrayList<E>` cannot hold a primitive type like int, so you declare it as `ArrayList<Integer>` and things get automatically "boxed" into `Integer` objects. For example:

   ```
   ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   myList.add(3);
   myList.add(5);
   System.out.println(myList.get(0) + myList.get(1)); // Prints "8".
   ```

The rule of thumb I use is: use an array when you know the size before hand and it's not going to grow, and use an arraylist otherwise.

Hope that helps.